# I can show images in a SPRING 3 MVC project

Tags: css, image, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I can`t show images in a Spring 3 MVC project. I don´t find the error and have been reading a lot of tutorials. My code is the next:

**dispatcher-servlet**

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />
<mvc:resources location="/resources/" mapping="/resources/**"/>

<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:jdbc.properties" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.barrancofv" />
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="hibernateTransactionManager"/>

    <bean id="jspViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="localeChangeInterceptor"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
    <property name="paramName" value="lang" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="localeResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver">
    <property name="defaultLocale" value="es"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="handlerMapping"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping">
    <property name="interceptors">
        <ref bean="localeChangeInterceptor" />
    </property>
    </bean>    

    <bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basenames">
        <list>
            <value>mymessages</value>
            <value>messages</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driver}" />
    <property name="url" value="${database.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${database.user}" />
    <property name="password" value="${database.password}" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
    <list>
        <value>com.barrancofv.model.Empleado</value>
        <value>com.barrancofv.model.Documento</value>
    </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="hibernateTransactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>
```

**web.xml**

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
       org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<listener>
<listener-class>
    org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
</listener-class>
</listener>

<context-param>
<param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
<param-value>
    /WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml,
    /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml
</param-value>
</context-param>

<filter>
<filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
<filter-class>
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
<filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

**Security.xml**

```
<http use-expressions="true">
    <!-- intercept-url seguridad de flujo de paginas -->
    <intercept-url pattern="/welcome" access="ROLE_USER" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/welcome/*" access="ROLE_USER" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/welcome/*/" access="ROLE_USER" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/welcome/*/*" access="ROLE_USER" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/welcome/*/*/" access="ROLE_USER" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/welcome/*/*/*" access="ROLE_USER" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/welcome/*/*/*/" access="ROLE_USER" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/welcome/*/*/*/*" access="ROLE_USER" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/resources/**" access="permitAll" />
    <form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/welcome" authentication-failure-url="/loginfailed" />
    <logout logout-success-url="/logout" />
</http>
```

**In my login.jsp**

To put my image, I use this:

```
<img src="<c:url value="/resources/img/a.jpg" alt="" />
```

My structure is:

```
src/main/resources/images/a.jpg
```

I don´t find the error. Thanks!!!

Comment: I'm not sure you have your image in the correct place. Where is your WEB-INF directory?

Comment: My WEB-INF directory is -->  src/main/webapp/WEB-INF  I use maven to create my project.

Answer (score 0):

You must configure a ressource handler in your spring configuration so that it matches your project structure

```
<!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources -->
<mvc:resources 
        mapping="/resources/** 
        location="/images/, classpath:/META-INF/web-resources/" />
```

And you need to add configure your security so that one can access this images wihtout login (to show them on the login page).

```
 <security:intercept-url pattern="/resources/**" access="permitAll" />
```

Comment: Thank u, I have configured my Security and I have edited the post and I have put the security.xml and my structure because already my project doesn´t work.

Answer (score 0):

I think its picking up the `resources` from the `webapp` folder.

Can you change the `resources` from `src/main/resources/` to `src/main/webapp/resources/` and try if that works.

Answer (score 0):

The issue Usha pointed out is partially correct.  You will want to move your resources to `src/main/webapp/resources` OR in your pom you can add `src/main/resources` as a webResource, which is different than a regular resource.

Secondly, you will not be referencing `/resources/images/...` in the JSP because your web resources will be placed in the root of the webapp, NOT within a /resources directory.

Finally, you have the DispatcherServlet mapped to the root context (/). In order to serve resources you should configure the [default-servlet-handler](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-default-servlet-handler).  You may also want to read the section before that documentation since it talks about serving resources.

In xml config it should be as easy as

```
<mvc:default-servlet-handler/>
```

Comment: In this moment there is another problem, the i18n of the project doesn´t work with the new changes :(

Comment: sounds like a totally separate problem. Perhaps you should ask another question.